# How would I assign a variable to each value in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.x

I want to assign a variable but the same variable just increased by one to each value in a list so for example `my_list=[[aa],[ab],[ba],[bb],[bc],[cb],[cc],[cd]]` and I want `d` to be the variable and have `d+=1` to proceed through the list for example the output to look more or less like, `value[0]=d0`, `value[1]=d1`, `value[2]=d2`, `value[3]=d3`, `value[4]=d4`, `value[5]=d5`, `value[6]=d6`, `value[7]=d7`.

```
def my_list():
    my_list=[[aa],[ab],[ba],[bb],[bc],[cb],[cc],[cd]] #list of values
    for d in my_list:
        d+=1 #? i don't know? how could i do this?
```

Comment: i don't know why it turned out so misshapen sorry i've been up for 25hrs working on this project and im stuck and frustrated and a beginner

Comment: np - those following the `python` tag are more than happy to help where possible in terms of formatting - kudos to @martinj for refomratting your post (we just don't tend to like posts from people that can't bother to formulate a question in an understable sense, etc...)

Comment: I think you need to get some sleep then, because your question does not make much sense at the moment.

Comment: Sometimes, it is better to describe the goal. The solution may be different than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for a list comprehension?

```
value = [d[0] for d in my_list]
```

A list comprehension lets you process each element of an iterable to produce a new list. The above example takes the first element of the nested lists, adding each to a new list. Your input list would then be transformed to:

```
[aa, ab, ba, bb, bc, cb, cc, cd]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way I thought of doing it:

```
def my_list(n):
   my_list, my_num, my_var = [], 0, '' #multiple assignment of variables
   for my_num in range(n + 1): #second argument is exclusive, this implies (0, n + 1)
      my_var = 'd' + str(my_num)
      my_list.append(my_var)
   return my_list
```

Alternatively, you can use dictionaries (same idea but a tad bit different):

```
def my_dict(n):
   my_dict, my_num, my_var = {}, 0, ''
   for my_num in range(n + 1):
      my_var = 'd' + str(my_num)
      my_dict[my_num] = my_var
   return my_dict
```

Where it would result in the key for each entry as `my_num` and the value is `my_var`. You can replace `'d'` with anything really, as long as it is a string. If it is not formatted as a string, and `my_num` is an integer or a floating-point number, it will add them together (`3 + 7` would result in `10`, not `37`), not concatenate them.

Comment: This is based off of my implication that you meant you want a list with values of a letter, 'd', and incremental numbers afterwards.